# How to fixed issue when encode/decode an video file using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I've an issue about encode/decode a video to new video has new width and height used to MediaCodec and MediaMuxer of Android platform.

The input video has size 1920x1080 and I want to encode this video to new videos has some size as 176x144,480x360,1280x720....But when I open file output has size 480x360,it don't like the input video.It can playing , but it look like broken display. And the output has size 176x144,1280x720 ... its look good ,same input video. I'm test on Nexus 4 (Android version 4.4.4).

I've been run CTS Test at  [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/7ddf78874d086e5bafd89ced7ffa9bfd3291ba32/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java) and the result like result above.

Can anyone help me understand the reason at here ?

Thanks you!

Comment: can you add a screenshoot? also it could be an issue in Nexus 4, since it is not covered with CTS test and is not in Google requirements

Comment: The video result look like http://youtu.be/F-GM4kunPBw.

Comment: This is a few months old, but we're seeing the same issue. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I have reviewed on CDD document at https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pd. And I found some output resolution look good, it include : 320x240,720x480,1280x720,1920x1080. I have tested on some my device (Nexus,Samsung,Sony) and i saw the output video look good. Hope it help you.

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this issue?